# AIML wildcards match V/S EXACT/NEAREST match

Tags: python, java, aiml

As I was trying AIML chatbot using AB.jar, when  I have a nearest match,chatbot is giving me a wildcard match response.

Suppose I have below categories ,

```
<aiml>
<category><pattern>^ NEFT ^ LIMIT</pattern>
  <template>NEFT_LIMIT</template>
</category>

<category><pattern>NEFT ^</pattern>
 <template><srai>NEFT_DEF</srai></template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

When I TRY TO CALL NEFT Transaction limit, I am getting response set for "NEFT ^", i.e. NEFT_DEF.

How to get response set for "^ NEFT ^ LIMIT" ?

Please let me know.

Comment: Why is this tagged Java and Python and has code for neither?

Answer (score 0):

AIML works by examining each part of the input and finding a path through its graph database. For an input such as "NEFT Transaction limit", it takes the first part `NEFT` and sees which category it matches. The choices being the `^` wildcard or `NEFT`, so naturally it matches your 2nd category. To override this, either change the `^` to `#` which overrides anything else or miss out the first `^` entirely.

```
<category>
    <pattern># NEFT ^ LIMIT</pattern>
    <template>NEFT_LIMIT</template>
</category>
```

Comment: Hi, As I have seen one of your blogs https://medium.com/pandorabots-blog/wildcards-in-aiml-da7f4a29f42e, I found that using # will override the exact match, whereas  ^ will be triggered only if there is no exact match. I think there is no provision to check nearest match.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by nearest match. You should use wildcards to activate a category that doesn't have an exact match. If you want to match NEFT Transaction Limit but don't want to use the # wildcard, miss out the first ^ to make the pattern NEFT ^ LIMIT

Comment: Currently i have following patterns 
1. ^ NEFT ^ LIMIT
2. ^ NEFT ^

My request mesaage for requesting limit will be
WHAT IS NEFT LIMIT or 
NEFT LIMIT or
NEFT TRANSACTION LIMIT.

My request mesaage for requesting definition of neft will be
WHAT IS NEFT or
NEFT or
NEFT TRANSACTION.

If I mention words both  NEFT  and LIMIT then it should filter through these,and should show me template attached to point 1. Not point 2.

Comment: My solution with the # wildcard will work with that situation. Anything with NEFT and LIMIT will trigger category 1